# Derive formula for Gaussian distribution of a matrix variable

Tags: probability, random-matrices

Let $J$ be a random matrix, i.e. all elements are drawn randomly, with zero mean and $\mathrm{E}[J_{ij}^2] = \frac{1}{N}$ and $\mathrm{E}[J_{ij}J_{ji}] = \frac{\tau}{N}$, then it is given that its Gaussian measure obeys the formula

$P(J) \propto \exp\big[ -\frac{N}{2(1 - \tau^2)}\mathrm{Tr}(JJ^T - \tau JJ) \big]$, where $J_{ij}^T = J_{ji}$.

How could this formula be derived ? From standard formula of Gaussian distribution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider first (as a warm-up exercise) a $2\times 2$ case. The matrix $\mathbf{J}$ can be parametrized as
$$
\mathbf{J}=        \begin{pmatrix}
        J_{11} & J_{12}  \\
        J_{21} & J_{22} \\
        \end{pmatrix}\ .
$$
If you evaluate the term $\frac{N}{2(1-\tau^2)}\mathrm{Tr}(\mathbf{J}\mathbf{J}^T-\tau \mathbf{J}\mathbf{J})$ you obtain
\begin{equation}
\frac{N \left(-\tau  \left(J_{11}^2+J_{12} J_{21}\right)+J_{11}^2+J_{12}^2-\tau  \left(J_{12}J_{21}+J_{22}^2\right)+J_{21}^2+J_{22}^2\right)}{2 \left(1-\tau ^2\right)}\ .
\end{equation}
Therefore, the term $\exp\left[-\frac{N}{2(1-\tau^2)}\mathrm{Tr}(\mathbf{J}\mathbf{J}^T-\tau \mathbf{J}\mathbf{J})\right]$ can be cast in the form of a multivariate Gaussian joint probability density (jpd)
$$
f_G(J_{11},J_{12},J_{21},J_{22})\propto \exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\vec{J}^T {\bf\Sigma}^{-1}\ \vec{J}\right]\ ,
$$
where $\vec{J}$ is a column vector $\vec{J}^T = (J_{11},J_{12},J_{21},J_{22})$, and ${\bf \Sigma}$ a $4\times 4$ *covariance matrix*. I let you work out the detailed form of ${\bf\Sigma}$. From the diagonal elements of ${\bf\Sigma}$, it should be easy to see that (for instance) $\mathbb{E}[J_{11}^2]=(1+\tau)/N$.
Of course, this 'proof' can be run backwards and for general $N$, so indeed you start from a multivariate Gaussian jpd for your $N^2$ matrix elements (arranged in a column vector), with a covariance matrix suitably constructed in order to accommodate your constraints on variances and covariances.